# 18.04.02 server - Static IP will not set during install

Tags: 18.04

I just pulled down a fresh copy of 18.04.02 server ISO. (ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso) During the install I try to set a static IP but when I select Save it just starts the install process over and goes right back to DHCP.  I have tested this on ESXi 6.5 and VirtualBox.

Comment: After a few more tests the issue seems to be if you put an entry in the domain search box.  if I leave that blank everything saves correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The new Subiquity Installer has a few problems, the alternate Ubuntu download (ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso) allows you to install using the traditional installer which is better until the issues are ironed out, YMMV.

Comment: This is a reported bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subiquity/+bug/1816954

Answer (score 0):

This [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subiquity/+bug/1816954) is fixed in a newer version of Ubiquity installer. If you experience this during installation, switch to tty2 (press ALT-F2 on your keyboard) and run

> $ snap refresh subiquity"

The installer will be refreshed, and you'll get a version of the installer with this bug fixed.

Switch back to tty1 (press ALT-F1) and continue setting up a manual IPv4 address. You may notice some text and options are slightly different.